# PyCharm warns about unresolved attribute for dict generated attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, warnings

Consider the following code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, config):
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.__setattr__(key, value)

    def foo(self):
        print(self.a)
```

PyCharm 2017.1.1 warns me about unresolved attribute `a` and I absolutely agree with it. But I don't want to write a blob of attributes in the constructor.

Is there any workaround to write the same functionality without warning? Or at least, how can I notify PyCharm not to warn me about attributes of this particular class?

Update: I don't want to disable PyCharm warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to please it:

```
def foo(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'a'):
        print(self.a)
```

Edit:
Warning, this is a bad idea! But, you can go into pycharm Preferences > Editor > Inspection, and under the Python section, disable the 'Unresolved references' check. This will make pycharm ignore the error, but it is a bad thing to do.

Comment: I have a lot of attributes and I'm trying to avoid writing a lot of attribute initializations. Your suggestion is to write a lot of `if` statements instead. No, thank you.

Comment: @RomanS I did not realise you had a lot of attributes that you wanted to do this with. Would having a single method that takes a string of an attribute name work? So it would check if the attr exists, and then print it? Or do you need each one to do something different?

Comment: Look at the first post. Quote: " But I don't want to write a blob of attributes in the constructor". So, I have `config: dict`, let say, read from yaml/json/etc file. And I can assign those config option values to object attributes using that simple loop. And I will use them all in some object methods. Your method `foo` is designed to work only with a single attribute, but I need to use all of them.

Comment: I know this. But you are completely right: it is a bad idea :) It would be great 
if there is a chance to turn it off for one class only ...

Comment: @RomanS unfortunately I don't think you are going to find what you're looking for, mostly because it is bad practice so you either turn off inspections or adjust your code for good practices. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree on the fact that dynamic attribute definition is not good idea.
At least, one can use the type definition if the set of to-be-for-sure attributes is known.

```
class SomeClass:
    a: str

    def __init__(self, config):
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.__setattr__(key, value)

    def foo(self):
        print(self.a)
```

Nevertheless, in order to disable the PyCharm (at least in the latest versions) warning for all the attribute references for one class you can define the `__getattr__` method.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, config):
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, name: str):
        return self.__dict__[name]
        # return super().__getattr__(name)  # it works but causes a PyCharm warning

    def foo(self):
        print(self.a)

# Verification
config = {"a" : "b"}
instance = SomeClass(config)
print(instance.a)
instance.foo()
```