# Instance attributes, generated from iterable with self.__setattr__. Is there a better way?

Tags: python, pycharm

When you setting attributes to an instance from some iterable like this:

```
class DogWith100Legs():
    def __init__(self, legs_colors):
        for leg_i, color in legs_colors.items():
            self.__setattr__(leg_i, color)

legs_colors = {'leg_1': 'white', 'leg_2': 'brown', ... , 'leg_100': 
'black'}
doge = DogWith100Legs(legs_colors)
print(doge.leg_100)
```

it works fine. But PyCharm will highlight leg_100 with a warning: "Unresolved reference 'leg_100' for class 'DogWith100Legs'.

Why i want to do this? I want to create tree-like object. Like BeautifulSoup do. But bs4 does not have such a problem in PyCharm

Also, there are comments in similar questions (like [PyCharm warns about unresolved attribute for dict generated attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658181/pycharm-warns-about-unresolved-attribute-for-dict-generated-attributes)), where people say, that it is a bad practice

What will be a good practice? Or may be you know a good way to calm down Pycharm? (Not disabling Pycharm check)

Comment: If you have dynamic attributes you should store them in a dictionary. The legs on the other hand could be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on intended usage.

1 If you are going to access the data directly by name, and there is no obvious relationship between items.

```
print(dog.leg_32)
print(dog.leg_5)
```

Only in this case is `__setattr__` fine.

2 You plan to retrieve the data indirectly, and/or there is some relationship (e.g. previous, next):

```
i = 25
print(dog.leg[i])
print(dog.leg[i+1])
```

In this case all data should be placed into a container (`list`, `dict` are the most common ones). Most probably this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm (and every other IDE) will give you warnings/errors because in `__init__` you have to declare every member of the object.

Because you are passing a dict, probably the best thing to do is to instantiate a dict into your class too, and then just get the value you need with the key `self.my_dict['leg_x']` and not `self.leg_x`.

```
class DogWith100Legs():
def __init__(self, legs_colors):
    self.legs_colors = legs_colors.copy()

legs_colors = {'leg_1': 'white', 'leg_2': 'brown', 'leg_100': 'black'}
doge = DogWith100Legs(legs_colors)
print(doge.legs_colors['leg_100'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink what you are trying to do a little bit - maybe even check out the BeautifulSoup source code to see how they do it.

In general though, there is no reason (that I can think of) to dynamically define instance attributes like this. You should simply have a `leg` dictionary or list within your `Dog` objects, like so:

```
def __init__(self, legs_colors: dict):
    self.legs_colors = legs_colors.copy()
```

Instance attributes should be individually important, but I doubt that you plan to use `leg_1` differently than you plan to use `leg_72`, especially since you can't guarantee that either of these attributes will exist with the way you have defined `__init__`.

Also, when you later access these leg attributes, you will likely want to do so dynamically. In which case you would have to resort to something like:

```
for leg in [f'leg_{i}' for i in range(100)]
    color = getattr(doge, leg)
    # do something with leg and color
```

instead of the simpler, clearer, and less smelly:

```
for leg, color in doge.legs_colors.items():
    # do something with leg and color
```

You can still program different interfaces for accessing your legs_colors dictionary, if you'd like to. For example, you could overwrite `__getitem__` on your Dog class if you want to be able to do `doge[i]` directly.